# Page Hit Counter With IP Info

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make my own page hit counter but have run into some errors.

Firstly I get an error:

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 21

Which correlates to this code:

```
<?php
// REQUIRE DB CONNECTION
$host = "host"; // Host name
$username = "username"; // Mysql username
$password = "password"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "database"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "info"; // Table name
$tbl_name2 = "hits"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

// CHECK IF PAGE EXISTS IN PAGE HIT TABLE
function checkPageName($page_name) {

    global $conn, $tbl_name2;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE page = $page_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (page, count) VALUES (:page, 0)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

// UPDATE PAGE HIT COUNT
function updateCounter($page_name) {

    global $conn, $tbl_name2;

    checkPageName($page_name);
    $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET count = count+1 WHERE page = $page_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

// UPDATE VISITOR INFO
function updateInfo() {

    global $conn, $tbl_name;

    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $datetime = date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (ip_address, user_agent, time_accessed) VALUES($ip_address, $user_agent, $datetime)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

The table info holds the ip address, user agent and time accessed, the hits table holds the page name and number of hits.

I call these functions on each page that I want to track. So for example I want to track my home page I add:

`updateCounter("Home");` and `updateInfo();`

I tested this code by refreshing the page and right now it's not updating anything at all

Comment: google produces 10 pages with results from SO about this error, is it really so hard to research before posting question?

Comment: Prepared statement would have prevented the need to add quotes around the values (`$page_name`)

Comment: @IlyaBursov I know I have googled the error, I have used mysqli_num_rows() before and never had a problem using very similar queries so that's why I am confused

Comment: @TheWelshManc why do you think that your case is special? have you even tried to use found answers? like mysql_error for example?

Comment: I've looked on that page and used mysqli_real_escape_string and mysql_error, didn't help

Comment: @AlonEitan just realised I never even had quotes around `$page_name`, d'oh!